# Prime Factors in JAVA

Tags: java, output, decomposition

I am trying to write a program that give an output as prime decomposition of a given number. However, my code gives correct answer as an output of `"2**2**2**2**2**5**7**7**11*"` but I want it specific output as `"(p1**n1)(p2**n2)...(pk**nk)"`. Here's my code:

```
public class PrimeDecomp
{
    public static String factors(int n)
    {
        String ans = "";
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                // checks if i is a divisor of num
                ans += i + "**";
                // writes i in prime factorization
                n = n/i;
                // since it is written down, num=num/i
                i--;
                // just in case their are multiple factors of same number.
                // For example, 12=2*2*3
            }
        }
        return (ans.substring(0, ans.length() - 1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(PrimeDecomp.factors(86240));
    }
}
```

Comment: /*public class PrimeDecomp {
 
 public static String factors(int n){
  
   String ans=""; 
      for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){ 
        if(n %i==0){ //checks if i is a divisor of num
          ans+= i+ "**"; //writes i in prime factorization
          n = n/i; //since it is written down, num=num/i
          i--; //just in case their are multiple factors of same number. For example, 12=2*2*3
        }
      }
      return(ans.substring(0,ans.length()-1));
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(PrimeDecomp.factors(86240));
 }

}*/

Comment: You might have noticed that comments don't format code very well.  You need to edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: Make sure you [format it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) too, please.

Comment: @RonOhare Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33175544/edit) on my comment or just below the tags on your question. Then view the link from my earlier comment on how to format your code.

Comment: How come you couldn't edit your question? There's the "edit" link at the bottom of your question (below the tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, instead of computing one factor at a time, compute all for the same factor and count them:

```
public static String factors(int n)
{
    String ans = "";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // Reset the counter
        count = 0;

        /*
         * Instead of only processing on factor, we process them all and
         * count them
         */
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            count++;
            n = n / i;
        }

        // If we have at least processed one add it to the string
        if (count == 1)
        {
            ans += "(" + i + ")";
        } else if (count > 0)
        {
            ans += "(" + i + "**" + count + ")";
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Since you are manipulating a string quite often in a loop, you should use `StringBuilder`

Comment: what if it is times 1 and only want the number not times 1? For example: {(2**5)(5**1)(7**2)(11**1)} and I want it as {(2**5)(5)(7**2)(11)}.

Comment: Add an if else, the first checks for count == 1, the other for count > 0. In count == 1 you just add the number to the string like ans += "(" + I + ")";